# How to invoke an HTML form from a drop menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am switching from buttons to a drop menu for user to log in or create an account.  The scripts below were working properly with buttons.  Wondering how to invoke the scripts from a drop menu as defined below.  Thanks.

```
<script>
    function openCreateAccountForm() {
        document.getElementById("createAccountForm").style.display = "block";        
    }

    function closeCreateAccountForm() {
        document.getElementById("createAccountForm").style.display = "none";
    }
    function openLoginForm() {
        document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeLoginForm() {
        document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hello</button>
    <div id="notLoggedInOpts" class="dropdown-content" >
        <a href="#">Login 1</a>
        <a href="#">Create Account 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the onClick attribute to the anchor tags shown below

```
<a onClick="openLoginForm()" href="#">Login 1</a>
<a onClick="openCreateAccountForm()" href="#">Create Account 2</a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: All great suggestions.  Daniel's was the lightest lift.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onclick event either inline `onclick="openLoginForm()"` or with an event listener `document.getElementById("#{class or id}").onclick = function() {openLoginForm();}` or you can just execute from the href property as `href="javascript:openLoginForm()"`

Comment: You should not that `$('#SELECTOR)` requires the jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you don't even need javascript for this.

You can link to an internal element on the page using id's and `#`. Then you can utilize `:target` with CSS to show the required form.

```css
#login,
#register {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
}

#login:target,
#register:target {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Hello</button>
  <div id="notLoggedInOpts" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#login">Login 1</a>
    <a href="#register">Create Account 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="login">
  Login Form Here
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<div id="register">
  Register Form Here
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

If you still wanted to go the javascript route, I would use unobtrusive javascript and generate event listeners.

```js
function showLoginRegisterForm(event) {
  //Get the # target from the link
  var target = event.target.getAttribute('href');
  //Optional : hide the other form
  document.querySelector("#forms > div:not(" + target + ")").style.display = "none";
  //Shoe the target form
  document.querySelector(target).style.display = "block";
}

function hideLoginRegisterForm(event) {
  //Get the # target from the link
  var target = event.target.getAttribute('href');  
  //Hide the target form
  document.querySelector(target).style.display = "none";
}

//Get our button to show forms 
var formButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#notLoggedInOpts a");

//Add Event Listeners to show
for (var i = 0; i < formButtons.length; i++) {
  formButtons[i].addEventListener("click", showLoginRegisterForm);
}

//Get our button to hide forms 
var formHideButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#forms a");

//Add Event Listeners to hide
for (var i = 0; i < formHideButtons.length; i++) {
  formHideButtons[i].addEventListener("click", hideLoginRegisterForm);
}
```

```css
#login,
#register {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Hello</button>
  <div id="notLoggedInOpts" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#login">Login 1</a>
    <a href="#register">Create Account 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="forms">
  <div id="login">
    Login Form Here
    <a href="#login" class="close">Close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="register">
    Register Form Here
    <a href="#register" class="close">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```